# Error turned out to be because of operator precedence

Tags: r

I'm trying to take the %CV of only the positive values in a triplicate, however something that appears to produce a reasonable numeric answer is breaking the dplyr code, and now I realize it's having all sorts of weird side effects even in base R.

What's going on here?

```
#why does this seem to give a reasonable numeric answer, then there are errors and unusual things?
testc <- c(0.183662273,0.175215584,-0.16)
sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100
sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100 %>% as.numeric() %>% str()
sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100 %>% as.numeric() %>% class()
sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100 %>% str()
sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100 %>% class()
```

Comment: Operator precedence issues. Put `()` around your expression: `(sd(testc[testc>0])/mean(testc)*100) %>% as.numeric() %>% class()`

Comment: Thanks, that was quick and now I feel silly but satisfied.